# I want to give less space ABOVE <HR> tag

Tags: html, css

Here is the js fiddle link I want to give less space between the h1 and the hr tag.

[jsfiddle.net/7oebee2m](http://jsfiddle.net/7oebee2m)

```
body{
    background: url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    word-wrap:break-word;

}
h1{
    font-family: "Sacramento";
}

.title{
   font-size: 20px;
    transition: color 2s, font-size 2s;
    float: none;
}
.title:hover{
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oebee2m/5/

```
.title > h1{
    font-family: "Sacramento";
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7oebee2m/3/

You can play with these margins and paddings in this section:

```
hr{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

h1{
    font-family: "Sacramento";
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**css:**

```
.specialH1{
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

**html:**

```
<hr>
<h1 class="specialH1">hifurfuufi</h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7oebee2m/4/